# How to speed up spring validation on SpringSource Tool suite?

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using version 3.0.0 of STS, and whenever I open a load of projects or do a build it is giving the message:

```
validating element <element here> with rule '@required property rule'
```

or similar messages

It is taking around two or three seconds per bean, and is going through every class file in my hierarchy.  This can take around 45 minutes for larger projects.

Are there any configuration settings which could help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a lack of memory causing the problem.  I'd try bumping up your Xmx to 1024m (default is 768m).  You can change this setting in your STS.ini.  It is colocated with the STS executable.